# Writing XML to Raw resource directory

Tags: android, xml

How do I write xml to a file in my raw directory.  I have everything nearly completed just need this last step.

```
XmlSerializer xmlWriter = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String namespace = "";
    try{
        xmlWriter.setOutput(writer);
        xmlWriter.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        xmlWriter.startTag("", "contacts");
        xmlWriter.startTag("", "entry");
        xmlWriter.attribute("", "entry", "String");
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++){
            xmlWriter.startTag("", "firstname");
            xmlWriter.text(sortedList.get(i).getFirstName());
            xmlWriter.endTag(namespace, "firstname" );
            xmlWriter.startTag(namespace, "lastname");
            xmlWriter.text(sortedList.get(i).getLastName());
            xmlWriter.endTag(namespace, "lastname");
            xmlWriter.startTag(namespace, "number");
            xmlWriter.text(sortedList.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
            xmlWriter.endTag(namespace, "number");
        }
        xmlWriter.endTag(namespace, "entry");
        xmlWriter.endTag(namespace, "contacts");
        xmlWriter.endDocument();


        xmlWriter.setOutput(writer);

        // Write to res/raw/contacts.xml
```

the writer has all the xml formatted properly and sorted the way I want it.  I just need to figure out how to write it to a file located in my res/raw folder.

**EDIT**
I am reading the file using XmlPullParser and an InputStream:

```
XmlPullParser xmlData;
    InputStream input = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.contacts);
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    xmlData = factory.newPullParser();
    xmlData.setInput(input, "UTF-8");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK that is not possible, you can write to the devices internalt/external storage or post your file to a webserver, but the raw folder is not modifiable it is read-only once your app is on the phone